# GoogleSignIn 5 doesn't provide correct code when the flow was canceled

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I've updated the `GoogleSignIn` pod from 4 to 5 and now it doesn't provide a proper error for cancelation anymore.

So, once the popup appears I press "Cancel".

[image: Google Auth Alert]

Now `AppAuth`, the underlying framework for `GoogleSignIn` since version 5, passes a proper cancel error to `GoogleSignIn` *(org.openid.appauth.general error -3)*. But `GoogleSignIn` wraps it into an *unknown* error *(com.google.GIDSignIn -1)*, so that you can't catch the cancel properly anymore:

**Method from GIDSignInDelegate:**

```swift
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)
```

**The error says this:**

> Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.openid.appauth.general error -3.)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.openid.appauth.general error -3.)}

Comment: is the sign still working for you when clicking on "Continue"? For me it worked one week ago, but stopped doing so yesterday. Now it returns the same `-3` error.